# AWS S3 lifecycle configuration filters to disable the storage class glacier to some folder in the same bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-glacier

I have a bucket that contains many folders and I have applied a lifecycle rule to the whole bucket initially and now I would like to exclude some folders (PREfixes like: folderA and FolderB/ContentA) within a bucket?

```
Bucket Structure:s3://mybucket/
                    -folderA
                    -FolderB/ContentA
```

```
LifecycleConfiguration: 
    Rules: 
      - 
        Prefix: organization_excluded/            
        Status: Disabled 
        Transitions: 
          - 
            StorageClass: GLACIER 
            TransitionInDays: 1
      - 
        Prefix: dbo/organization_excluded/              
        Status: Disabled 
        Transitions: 
          - 
            StorageClass: GLACIER 
            TransitionInDays: 1
      -                           
        Status: Enabled 
        Transitions: 
          - 
            StorageClass: GLACIER 
            TransitionInDays: 1
```

In the above filter rule after one day entire content changed to the storage class as Glacier but my requirement would be the PREfixes like: folderA and FolderB/ContentA should not changed to Glacier as I have disabled, it's because of TransitionInDays set to 1, if I remove the TransitionInDays parameter for the prefix folders stack is failed, is there thing I have missed here.

Answer (score 0):

Having `Status: Disabled` it only means Amazon S3 does not take any action on disabled rules [check here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-ex1). So basically those rules are useless. Atm there is no way to exclude directly some prefix.